# How to count bigrams using a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, n-gram

I have a specific coding question in python.

```
Count = defaultdict(int)
for l in text:
   for m in l['reviews'].split():
      Count[m] += 1

print Count
```

The `text` is a list that looks like following

```
[{'ideology': 3.4,
 'ID': '50555',
 'reviews': 'Politician from CA-21, very liberal and aggressive'},{'ideology': 1.5,
 'ID': '10223'
 'reviews': 'Retired politician'}, ...]
```

If I run this code, I get a result like this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'superficial,': 2, 'awesome': 1, 
'interesting': 3, 'A92': 2, ....
```

What I want to get is a bigram count, instead of unigram count. I tried following code, but I get an error `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

```
Count = defaultdict(int)
for l in text:
    for m in l['reviews'].split():
       Count[m, m+1] += 1
```

I want to use a similar code like this instead of using other codes that already exist in Stackoverflow. Most of the existing codes use word list, but I want to count bigrams directly from the split() which come from the original text.

I want to get a result similar like this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('superficial', 'awesome'): 1, ('awesome, interesting'): 1, 
('interesting','A92'): 2, ....}
```

Why do I get an error and how do I fix this code?

Comment: Hmm...I don't understand. What's `l` or `text`? Also what's the expect output?

Comment: I think merletta's answer below is what you're looking for. If you want to understand your error `m+1` is interpreted by Python as a string concatenation request; indeed `m` is a string and it overloads the `+` operator. But as your know `1` is an integer, not a string, hence the error. You probably intended `m` to be an integer too; if so you should first have saved the list `words = l['reviews'].split()` and second used it with `for m in xrange(len(words))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is solution for counting objects in standard library, called [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).
Also, with the help of [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes), your bigram counter script can look like this:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from itertools import izip, tee

#function from 'recipes section' in standard documentation itertools page
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

text = [{'ideology': 3.4, 'ID': '50555',
 'reviews': 'Politician from CA-21, very liberal and aggressive'},
 {'ideology': 1.5, 'ID': '10223',
 'reviews': 'Retired politician'} ]

c = Counter()
for l in text:
   c.update(pairwise(l['reviews'].split()))

print c.items()
```

Comment: That's the best Python solution I think. Does `izip` stop when one of the two iterators is/evaluates to `None`? This is important because you don't want to count tuples like `(word,None)`.

Comment: yes, it stops. From documentation, "Like zip() except that it returns an iterator instead of a list". And `zip` truncates output to the length of shortest argument, pairs with `None` won't appear.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, below codes solve your problem.

```
 Count = dict()
    for l in text:
        words = l['reviews'].split()
        for i in range(0,len(words) -1):
            bigram  = " ".join(words[i:i+2] )
            if not bigram  in Count:
                Count[bigram] = 1;
            else:
                Count[bigram] = Count[bigram] + 1
```

Count would be:

```
> {'CA-21, very': 1, 'liberal and': 1, 'very liberal': 1, 'and
> aggressive': 1, 'Politician from': 1, 'aggressive Politician': 1,
> 'from CA-21,': 1}
```

Edit:if you want to use key as tuple just change the join line. python dict hashes tuples too.

Comment: To the OP: I think you should trim punctuation (`,/!?` etc) and use tuples. Also you need to know whether the order of the digram counts or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to count the number of each two adjacent words ? Make them a tuple.

```
text = [{'ideology':3.4, 'ID':'50555', 'reviews':'Politician from CA-21, very liberal and aggressive'}]
Count = {}
for l in text:
   words = l['reviews'].split()
   for i in range(len(words)-1):
        if not (words[i],words[i+1]) in Count:
                Count[(words[i],words[i+1])] = 0
        Count[(words[i],words[i+1])] += 1

print Count
```

result:

{('and', 'aggressive'): 1, ('from', 'CA-21,'): 1, ('Politician', 'from'): 1, ('CA-21,', 'very'): 1, ('very', 'liberal'): 1, ('liberal', 'and'): 1}

Comment: Thank you! I get result like this: `defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('b', '.'): 31, ('-', ' '): 1025, ('.', 'A'): 5,...`  Your second line calls each letter not word. I am trying to change your code to fix the problem.